# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "olerse la tostada"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, coloquialismos

Una de las acepciones de [oler](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QzRk6op) es

> 3. tr. coloq. Conocer o **adivinar algo que se juzgaba oculto**, barruntarlo. U. m. c. prnl. Me *huelo* que no vendrá a la boda. U. t. c. intr. Me *huele* que será niña.

quizá porque una señal "olfativa" o un olor sea menos evidente que algo que podemos ver u oír (comparemos "Me *huelo* que no vendrá a la boda" con "Veo que no vendrá a la boda" o "ya he oído que no vendrá a la boda". Pareciera que lo que podemos percibir por vista u oído sea más evidente que lo perceptible a través del sentido del olfato).

Hay además una locución adverbial (un coloquialismo o expresión) que es `olerse la tostada`. En el DRAE, [explican](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a9nyhxW)

> **olerse la tostada**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Adivinar o descubrir algo oculto, como una artimaña, una trampa, etc.

¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "olerse la tostada"? Es decir ¿Hay alguna cita o pasaje literario famosos en el que se relaciones un "olerse la tostada" (literal) con descubrir algo? ¿Hay alguna razón en especial para que sea una "tostada" en lugar de otra cosa?

Ninguna de las acepciones del DRAE para [tostada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a9nyhxW) lleva a pensar que pueda ser algo que se pretende ocultar o algo llamativo, que favoreciese esa expresión de "olerse la tostada" frente a otra cosa.

Comment: It is interesting that in English we also use the sense of smell in similar circumstances: smell a rat, something smells fishy. I think your contrast with vision is helpful as smell can creep up on you unawares, the smell of something burning (perhaps even the toast), the smell of gas.

Answer (score 2):

No es una respuesta rigurosa, pero yo siempre he pensado que se debe al propio olor de las tostadas, de forma literal.

Me refiero a que una rodaja de pan no desprende olor hasta que comienza a tostarse. Entonces me evoca la típica escena de anuncio de comida, en la que una persona de la pareja se está haciendo un desayuno a escondidas, pero no puede ocultar el agradable aroma de la comida que está haciendo. Podría ser solo eso.